# Multifile dialog from multiple directories

Tags: python, wxpython

I am trying to open a multifile dialog that can select multiple files from multiple directories.. I am currently using wx for my multifile dialog which works great for opening multiple files in the same directory, yet when I try to select another directory the last file gets un-selected.
ie: I want to be able to open c:\directory1 and click file1
then I went to open c:\directory2 and click file 2
So my path list should look something like "c:\directory1\file1""c:\directory2\file2"
Can this be done?
Here is my current code

```
app = wx.App(False)
dialog = wx.FileDialog(None, message="Choose File(s)",
                         defaultDir=startDirectory,
                         style=(wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_MULTIPLE))
if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
    paths = dialog.GetPaths()
    log.info('You chose the following Path(s):')
    for path in paths:
        log.debug('{}'.format(  path))
    dialog.Destroy()
    return paths
```

Thank you!

Comment: thats not how it works...you can only select multiple files/folders in the same directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would need to make your own file dialog class to do this...

Comment: Are there any other modules that might support this other than wxpython?

Comment: nope not that I know of at least... thats just not how they work typically